# How to disable a CKEditor5 package loaded by core?

Tags: 10

Is there a way to disable a CKEditor5 package loaded by core? I would like to disable `paste-from-office`, but I can see the question here applying to different packages.

In the file `web/core/core.libraries.yml` we see this code:

```
ckeditor5.pasteFromOffice:
  remote: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5
  version: "35.4.0"
  license:
  name: GNU-GPL-2.0-or-later
  url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/v35.4.0/LICENSE.md
  gpl-compatible: true
js:
  assets/vendor/ckeditor5/paste-from-office/paste-from-office.js: { minified: true }
dependencies:
  - core/ckeditor5
```

I tried removing it but now when CKEditor loads on an edit page it complains about the missing library.

We also have in `web/core/modules/ckeditor5/ckeditor5.ckeditor5.yml`

```
ckeditor5_pasteFromOffice:
  ckeditor5:
    plugins: [pasteFromOffice.PasteFromOffice]
  drupal:
    label: Paste From Office
    library: core/ckeditor5.pasteFromOffice
    elements: false
    conditions: []
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable rich-text paste from office365.com by adding this code to one of my custom CKE5 modules:

```
editor.editing.view.document.on('clipboardInput', (evt, data) => {
  data.content = editor.data.htmlProcessor.toView(data.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
});
```

I was able to disable rich-text paste from the Word app by removing the reference to it in `ckeditor5.ckeditor5.yml` quoted above.

No errors!